# How to skip validation in django model serializers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Its a general question.
I have a code where I have implemented the validation of the serializer. Now when I make a `post` request and validate the data by `is_valid` function, it should run the `validate` method. But when I make a `patch` request it validates the data again. I want to skip this part because in my `validate` function I am validating data using some fields which are sent by the client during the `post` request but not during the `patch` request. I am not sure how to deal with this. Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to compare `view.action == partial_update`.

Example:

```py
if view.action == 'partial_update':
    return attrs
```

Answer (score 0):

In serializer validate method, you can skip validation like:

```
def validate(self, data):
    # self.partial will be True if the request type is patch
    if self.partial:
        return
```